# Troca de Branch

Tags: git

Preciso de ajuda pra trocar a branch de uma pasta.
Eu vou participar de um projeto open source no github, entao clonei a pasta que eu preciso atraves do git, mas a pasta ficou na branch master e eu preciso dela em outra branch. Eu criei uma nova branch, mas agora eu nao sei como tirar essa pasta da branch master e colocar nessa nova branch que eu criei.
Quando eu abro a pasta no visual studio eu consigo ver que ela ta na branch master.
Eu sou iniciante no git/github.
Obrigada.

Comment: tenta: git checkout nomeDaBranch

Comment: Eu tive um problema parecido, só que ja tem uns meses e não lembro ao certo como resolvi. Tente ver nesse link tem uma seção que se chama "Switch branch using git switch". Segue o link:https://devconnected.com/how-to-switch-branch-on-git/ Boa sorte...

Comment: Primeira coisa que vc tem que fazer é um `git pull`, depois `git checkout suaBranch` etc. Ou então começa de novo, entra na master, da um pull, cria uma branch nova e toca o barco

Answer (score 0):

Basta dar o seguinte código:

git checkout {nome-da-branche-ja-existente}

com:
git branch

Você consegue ver todas as branchs existentes.

Porém se estiver tendo problemas com git flow, existe um plugin que pode ser instalado no projeto que cuida dessa parte complicada:

sudo apt-get install git-flow

git flow init
git flow feature start {ProductPage}
git flow feature finish {ProductPage}

onde está escrito feature, fica o nome do tipo de programação que você irá criar, se é uma feature, ou bugfix, e etc.

Há também um módulo para a aplicação que padroniza os commits e etc

O módulo é o  commit:
yarn add commit